# How to make null values come last when sorting with multiple column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

```
CREATE TABLE #sorttest (test int, test2 int)

INSERT INTO #sorttest 
VALUES (1, 2), (5, 4), (4, 3), (NULL, 1),
       (3, NULL), (2, 5)

SELECT *
FROM #sorttest
ORDER BY    
    CASE WHEN test IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, test DESC

DROP TABLE #sorttest
```

How to sort the output so that for both columns, `NULL` comes last?

[image]

Comment: What's your ultimate desired order? Should `(3, NULL)` come before or after `(NULL, 1)`?

Comment: I'm sure your SQL did sort NULL to the bottom.  You can't really sort both NULL's to the bottom, because they don't belong in the same row.

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the data so the bottom row is (NULL,NULL) ?

Comment: I want both null value come last.

Comment: Only one row can come last, by definition. If you don't care what the relative order between `(3, NULL)` and `(NULL, 1)` is, just that they both appear in the last two spots, include that in the question. Better yet, just write out the rows in the desired order so there's no ambiguity about what you're after. Note that `(NULL, NULL)` is *not* part of your input, nor is `(3, 1)`. Think about what should happen if `NULL`s don't line up!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @sorttest TABLE ( test1 INT, test2 INT)

INSERT INTO @sorttest values
(1,2),(5,4),(4,3),(NULL,1),(3,null),(2,5)

DECLARE @temp1 TABLE ( ID1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, test3 INT )
DECLARE @temp2 TABLE ( ID2 INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, test4 INT )

INSERT INTO @temp1
SELECT test1 FROM @sorttest ORDER BY test1 DESC

INSERT INTO @temp2
SELECT test2 FROM @sorttest ORDER BY test2 DESC

SELECT test3, test4 FROM @temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN @temp2 t2 ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID2
```

I manipulated the data using 2 other temporary tables to get the desired output using a join statement.

If you need to rearrange values within a row, more logic is needed than a single select statement.

OUTPUT:

```
test3   test4
5       5
4       4
3       3
2       2
1       1
NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
SELECT * FROM #sorttest ORDER BY
CASE WHEN test IS NULL and test2 is null THEN 2 ELSE 
   case when test is null or test2 is null then 1 end 
   END ,test desc
```

but then the ordering of the non-null column is a bit odd

Comment: i want both null column at last potion

Comment: SELECT *
FROM #sorttest
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(test2, 2147483647) ,test2,